# How to install ICU plugin for elastic search 6.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, icu

The command given in official documentation is not working for me.
the command is:

```
./bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu/$VERSION
```

replaced $VERSION as 2.7.0

```
./bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu/2.7.0
```

I am running the command from the elastic search home directory.

```
~/elasticsearch-6.1.1$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be referring to outdated documentation.

The correct way to install the ICU analysis plugin on 6.1.1 is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.1/analysis-icu.html), i.e. run this command from our $ES_HOME folder

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```